# Where are Postgres host and port details stored in Redash

Tags: python-3.x, redash

Please help me to find where the details (hostname,port number etc.) are stored in redash. I have checked in redash database-**data_sources** table, found Name - **PG** stored in the table,but could not find host and portnumber.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Below is the image for Data Source setting.
[image: Data Source settings]

Comment: Just a guess but can it be in encrypted_options field in data_sources table?

Comment: Yes, I verified. Those details are encrypted and stored as encrypted_options in data_sources table. Thank you.